# Racket GUI toolkit: how to allow a message% with a long label

Tags: racket

Say we have code of the form:

```
#lang racket/gui

(define my-frame (new frame% [label "test"]))

(define some-string "A very long hello world .......................................................................................................................................................................................................")

(define my-msg (new message% [parent my-frame]
                [label some-string]))

(send my-frame show #t)
```

Code of this form results into an error, because `message%` expects a `label-string`, which is a string that consists of 200 charachters or less. How can one have a `message%` of more than 200 charachters?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use `message%`? There is [`text-field%`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text-field_.html), you can disable it and set its value to your string.

```
#lang racket/gui

(define my-frame (new frame%
                      [label "Frame"]
                      [min-width 1000]
                      [min-height 500]))

(define some-string "A very long hello world .......................................................................................................................................................................................................")

(define my-msg (new text-field%
                    [label ""]
                    [init-value some-string]
                    ;[style (list 'multiple)]
                    [parent my-frame]
                    [enabled false]))

(send my-msg set-field-background (make-object color% 240 240 240))

(send my-frame show #t)
```

If your string contains some newlines, uncomment `[style (list 'multiple)]` option.

Comment: Although this is a nice suggestion, I want a transparent background for my text, which is the default behavior of a message%. Is that possible with a text-field%

Comment: @TurgutKursun I found `set-field-background` function (see edit), but that doesn't remove border...

Comment: I think you have to use `editor-canvas%` with `no-border` to remove it.